# Percentage of rate reduction

Tags: descriptive-statistics, percentage

I have two rates (# of incidences per # of visits):
older - 2.33
newer - 1.33

Would it be appropriate to say that the rate was reduced by 43 percent ((1.33/2.33)-1)?

Comment: Depending on context and what the reader expects: yes, you could say something like "The # of incidences per # of visits dropped from 2.33 to 1.33, a decrease of 1.00 (43%)". If you decide to go with the absolute percentage you could make that explicit, e.g., "The rate decreased from 233% to 133% (100% absolute).